# Formula is not count it correctly based on the date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has opening and closing checklist. Basically, I want the T3 to count all missed openings and U3 to count all missed closings up to the current date. For some reason, the opening is working fine but closing is counting the future dates.

Currently, the date is April 29.

E1:R1 is the range of the dates
E3:R3 is the range of the checkboxes

The formula I have for T3 is: =SUMPRODUCT((E3:R3=FALSE)*(MOD(COLUMN(E3:R3)-COLUMN(E1),2)=0)*($E$1:$R$1<=TODAY()))

While this is what I have for U3: =SUMPRODUCT((E3:R3=FALSE)*(MOD(COLUMN(E3:R3)-COLUMN(E1),2)=1)*($E$1:$R$1<=TODAY()))

[image]

Comment: You have tagged both Excel and Sheets. Which are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies between merged cell header for your date. Merged cells only store the actual value in the top left cell: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135735079/merged-cells-only-have-a-value-on-first-cell-rest-of-the-cells-act-as-if-they-were-empty

Therefore, when you are comparing with `$E$1:$R$1<=TODAY()`, those alternative cells (eg. F1, H1, J1, L1, N1, P1, R1) actually has no values (default to `0`), that's why `<= TODAY()` condition will always return `true`.

One workaround you can apply is, create a new row and hide it, then refer to that row instead, for example:

```
|   |     A      |     B      |     C      |     D      |
| 1 |        2023-04-28       |        2023-04-28       |
| 2 | 2023-04-28 | 2023-04-28 | 2023-04-29 | 2023-04-29 |
```

Formula for your row 2 could be:

```
| 2 | =A1        | =A2        | =B1        | =B2        |
```

After that, you refer to this row 2 for checking of date instead:

`$A$2:$D$2<=TODAY()`, since unmerged cells will ensure all cells have the values specified.

Comment: This is a great alternative and it's working, thank you!

Comment: Btw, can you please help me also with the Completion Rate? For some reason, with my formula, it's counting the future dates as well. I have updated my absolutes with the workaround you have provided already. If I check all the boxes, it will give me 117%. It's supposed to ignore April 30 checkboxes if that date is the future.

=COUNTIF(E4:R4,TRUE)/(COUNTIF($E$2:$R$2,"<="&TODAY()))

Comment: Hi @Foxseiz, usually that should be another question but I will help you this time :) You can make use of `COUNTIFS` in that case: `=COUNTIFS(E4:R4,TRUE,$E$2:$R$2,"<="&TODAY())/(COUNTIF($E$2:$R$2,"<="&TODAY()))`

Answer (score 2):

In Excel try:

```
T3: =SUM((INDEX($E3:$R3,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($E3:$R3)/2,1,2))=FALSE)*(INDEX($E$1:$R$1,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($E$1:$R$1)/2,1,2))<=TODAY()))

U3: =SUM((INDEX($E3:$R3,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($E3:$R3)/2,2,2))=FALSE)*(INDEX($E$1:$R$1,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS($E$1:$R$1)/2,1,2))<=TODAY()))
```

Note that the portion of the formula that refers to the Date always refers to the left hand cell of the Merged cell.

*The difference between the two formulas is in the first `SEQUENCE` function*.

Comment: Parameter 1 of the SEQUENCE function is 0.

Comment: @Foxseiz Not necessarily so in excel. The formula works as I wrote it without modifying your worksheet set-up.

Comment: I only beat you by about 10 seconds Ron - sorry. Have an upvote ;) .

Comment: @DavidBacci No apologies necessary. But tks.